# Moving element from grid row 1 to grid row 2 in run time ( in code )

Tags: wpf, grid

i need to move some button that exist in grid row 1 to grid row 2 in run time - in the code ..

How can i do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the attached property Grid.Row. Example

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Name="button"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Content="Some content"/>
</Grid>
```

Change row in code behind

```
Grid.SetRow(button, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Grid.Row`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.row.aspx) is a dependency property, so you could bind it to a property in your viewmodel if you're using MVVM.

```
<Button Grid.Row="{Binding Path=ButtonRow}" />
```